# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, mamp

I really need help I searched in all the questions I found on stackoverflow and nothing works. I have never used hibernate before and I don't know what I am doing wrong. I generated tables but with insertions I have problems.

I get this error:

```
20-May-2017 10:53:41.085 WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl.handleException GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
 org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:245)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at gameplatform.servlet.IndexPage.init(IndexPage.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot add foreign key constraint
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2497)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2455)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:839)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:739)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 32 more
```

this is my configurations file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/gameplatform</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="db.table.template.Permesso"/>
        <mapping class="db.table.template.PermessoTemplate"/>
        <mapping class="db.table.template.PermessoTemplateId"/>
        <mapping class="db.table.template.Template"/>
        <mapping class="db.table.template.Gruppo"/>
        <mapping class="db.table.template.Utente"/>
        <mapping class="db.table.template.Livello"/>
        <mapping class="db.table.template.Gioco"/>
        <mapping class="db.table.template.Giocare"/>
        <mapping class="db.table.template.GiocareId"/>
        <mapping class="db.table.template.Trofeo"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

this is my test page:

```
package gameplatform.servlet
public class TestPage extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public TestPage() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

    Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure();
    Session session = conf.buildSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Permesso permesso = new Permesso();
    permesso.setNome("Index");
    permesso.setIndirizzo("gameplatform.op");

    Template template = new Template("slider.jsp");
    session.saveOrUpdate(template);

    PermessoTemplate permessoTemplate = new PermessoTemplate();
    permessoTemplate.setPermesso(permesso);
    permessoTemplate.setTemplate(template);
    permessoTemplate.setPriority(3);

    permesso.getPermessoTemplate().add(permessoTemplate);

    session.saveOrUpdate(permesso);

    Query query = session.createQuery("from Template template join template.permessoTemplate joinPage where joinPage.pk.permesso = 'Index' order by joinPage.priority");
    List<Template> temp = query.list();

    Iterator it = temp.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) { 
        Object[] obj = (Object[]) it.next();
        Template test = (Template) obj[0];
        response.getWriter().append(" " + test.getIndirizzo());          
    }

    Gruppo test = new Gruppo("Admin");
    session.saveOrUpdate(test);

    Utente user = new Utente("Romolo", "De Roma", 20, "Er Zezzo", "Prova", "test@test.it", 3000, 3);
    user.setGruppo(test);
    test.getUtente().add(user);
    test.getPermesso().add(permesso);

    session.saveOrUpdate(user);

    /*Recensione recensione = new Recensione();
    recensione.setDescrizione("Gioco Bello");
    recensione.setVoto(4);
    recensione.setUtente(user);

    session.saveOrUpdate(recensione);*/

    Query control = session.createQuery("from Livello");
    List<Livello> controlList = control.list();

    boolean bool = false;
    Iterator iter = controlList.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) { 
        //Object[] obj = (Object[]) 
        Livello lv = (Livello) iter.next();

        if (lv.getLivello()==3 && lv.getUtente().getUsername().equals(user.getUsername())){
            bool=true;
        }
    }
    if (!bool){
        Livello livello = new Livello();
        livello.setLivello(3);
        livello.setDate(new GregorianCalendar(2017,5,20));
        livello.setUtente(user);

        session.saveOrUpdate(livello);
    }

    Gioco gioco = new Gioco();
    gioco.setNome("Zezzo");
    gioco.setDescrizione("Bel Gioco Di Merda");
    gioco.setSpecifiche("2Gb di Rom");

    Giocare giocare = new Giocare();
    giocare.setExp(3000);
    giocare.setMinuti(new Time(2000));
    giocare.setNumAccessi(30);
    giocare.setRecensione("Bello ma Brutto");
    giocare.setVoto(5);
    giocare.setUtente(user);
    giocare.setGioco(gioco);

    gioco.getGiocare().add(giocare);

    session.saveOrUpdate(gioco);

    Trofeo trofeo = new Trofeo();
    trofeo.setNome("Test");
    trofeo.setIcona("icona.jpg");
    trofeo.setObiettivo(5);
    trofeo.setGioco(gioco);
    user.getTrofeo().add(trofeo);

    session.saveOrUpdate(trofeo);

    session.getTransaction().commit();

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}}
```

this is my IndexPage:

```
package gameplatform.servlet;

    public class IndexPage extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String pageName;
    private String[] template;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public IndexPage() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.init(config);
    this.pageName = getInitParameter("pageIndex");

    Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure();
    Session session = conf.buildSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    String query = "from Template template join template.permessoTemplate joinPage where joinPage.pk.permesso = ? order by joinPage.priority";
    List execute = session.createQuery(query).setString(0, pageName).list();

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    Iterator it = execute.iterator();
    int i = 0;
    this.template = new String[execute.size()];
    while (it.hasNext()) { 
        Object[] obj = (Object[]) it.next();
        Template temp = (Template) obj[0];  ;
        this.template[i] = temp.getIndirizzo();
        i++;
    }

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    process(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    process(request, response);
}

private void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    request.setAttribute("template", this.template);

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("JSP/index.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
}}
```

This is my SQL logs:

```
    2017-05-20 10:53:45 70000ed64000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2017-05-20 10:53:45 70000ed64000 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "gameplatform"."giocare" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
2017-05-20 10:53:45 70000ed64000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2017-05-20 10:53:45 70000ed64000 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "gameplatform"."gioco" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
2017-05-20 10:53:45 70000ed64000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2017-05-20 10:53:45 70000ed64000 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "gameplatform"."gruppo" but the required 
system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
2017-05-20 10:53:45 70000ed64000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2017-05-20 10:53:45 70000ed64000 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "gameplatform"."permessogruppo" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
2017-05-20 10:53:45 70000ed64000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2017-05-20 10:53:45 70000ed64000 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "gameplatform"."trofeo" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
2017-05-20 10:53:45 70000ed64000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2017-05-20 10:53:45 70000ed64000 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "gameplatform"."utente" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
2017-05-20 10:53:45 70000ed64000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2017-05-20 10:53:45 70000ed64000 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "gameplatform"."utentetrofeo" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
2017-05-20 11:54:17 70000ecdc000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
2017-05-20 11:54:46 70000ec54000 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your dialect engine change to your mysql dialect add the following lines, particularly if you are using spring boot, in your application.properties located under src/main/resources folder.

```
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Comment: Format your answer

Answer (score 1):

I had this exception with SprintBoot 2.x, by changing dialect it got resolved.
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

Comment: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, your Hibernate JDBC driver has a problem when executing a script(DDL) toward mysql database.

In the error, there is proper explanation:
there is exception on the SQL query with error "Cannot add foreign key constraint".

You have multiple Tables mapped, so I suggest to go one by one and see which table generation is having the Error. This will guide you to understand the Constrain Error that you have.

Error log that you provided is not relevant as it shows statistical tables errors that are replaces with other statistic for the db engine execution.

Thanks

Comment: I had the errors for each one (table that had a foreign key); I changed the compiler and it works: Eclipse creates the db in the right way without problems. thank you for the help

Comment: You could add this in problem description, as the db log is misleading. The answer is still one possible problem and I see no reason to down-vote if it is not in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, and what bring me out from this exception, has been illustrated in below steps -

1. Changed `<hibernate-configuration name="">` tag to `<hibernate-configuration>` inside hibernate.cfg.xml file.
2. Always mention connection tag along with the localhost, port and the schema name or database name like - 
   `<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/protein_tracker</property>`

and these makes the execution free of exception, it works for me, hope it will also helps you a bit!